# How to configure TeXstudio editor for multibib?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, multibib

I want to use multiple bibliographies for which I am using following code. However, I realize that I need to configure my text editor to properly process this code but I don't have any idea how.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{journal,conference}{Refereed Journal Articles, Refereed Conference Publications}

\begin{document}
Hi, this is an example of the multibib.
\bibliographystylejournal{plain}
\nocitejournal{*}
\bibliographyjournal{journal}

\bibliographystyleconference{plain}
\nociteconference{*}
\bibliographyconference{conference}

\end{document}
```

My conference.bib  and journal.bib file are:

```
@inproceedings{entry1,
    author = {Author name},
    address = {address},
    booktitle = {Some conference},
    title = {Title},
    year = {2013},
}
```

and

```
@article{entry2,
    author = {Author name},
    journal = {Some Journal},
    title = {Title},
    year = {2013},
}
```

Ask asked by Harish Kumar, here is the screenshot of my TexStudio configuration.
[image]

Ask asked by Harish Kumar, here is my log and output after compiling with arara
[image]
[image]

Comment: It is better to use `arara` with which you will not have to struggle.

Comment: @HarishKumar. What is this 'arara'? Can you please give some details how to make multiple bibliographies using 'arara'?

Comment: I have added an answer with details. Hope that is useful. If you have any further queries, feel free to ask.

Comment: @HarishKumar. Thanks. I will try this and let you know how it went.

Comment: @HarishKumar Today finally I installed the  arara. Initially it gave me an error that 'arara' could not be started. I figured out there was an error in the path because with cut paste from your instructions, the -1 changed to -|. So I fixed it and ran it again from  the user command that was created. Apparently it ran arara but no bibliography is produced. I only get one line of text in the output. (I copied your MWE).

Comment: How can i post the image? I tried pasting but I guess there is some other way that i don't know.

Comment: @HarishKumar. I could only include image in my initial question so I have posted it. My log says No file journal.bbl and No file conference.bbl

Comment: Please post your log too in the question. If you have run my code exactly, there shouldn't be any problem. BTW does arara start like in my last screen shot?

Comment: @HarishKumar. I have posted both above.

Comment: I think you typed `1` in `"C:/Program Files/arara/arara.exe" -v -l % | txs:///view`. It is *ell* → l not `1` (one). Can you confirm this?

Comment: @HarishKumar. You were right, I changed it to ell. However, it still did not work. Then I played around with the spaces between all characters and finally it worked. Thank you very much Harish.

Comment: Tash: Glad it worked finally. Happy `multibib`ing. :)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[arara](https://github.com/cereda/arara) is a cool tex automation tool. It comes bundled with TeX Live. If you using MiKTeX, you can install it by yourself. It comes with a neat documentation which you can refer to, for more details.

Coming to your problem, there are three steps.

**Running `multibib`**

If you define your `multibib` like:

```
\newcites{journal, conference}{Refereed Journal Articles, Refereed Conference Publications}
```

You have to run (assuming your main file is `main.tex`)

```
pdflatex main
bibtex main
bibtex journal
bibtex conference
pdflatex main
pdflatex main
```

Now we will see how to do these compilations using `arara`.

**Install `arara`**

If you are using TeX Live, you may skip this step. Install arara and ensure that `arara.exe` is in your system path. The installer will give an option to do this, hence be watchful to read the instructions during installation.

**Integrate `arara` with `texstudio`**

In `texstudio`, go to `Options` → `Configure TeXstudio`. In the window that opens, choose `Build` on the left side:

[image]

Under `User Commands`, type

```
"C:/Program Files/arara/arara.exe" -v -l % | txs:///view
```

(replace `C:/Program Files/arara/` with your path) or

```
arara -v -l % | txs:///view
```

(if `arara` is in system path)

as in the above figure. Also don't forget to give this a name (`user0: Arara`). Now `OK` the window.

Now under the menu `Tools` → `User`, you will have `arara` with a short cut.

[image]

**Putting `directives`**

You have to provide directives to `arara` on a document basis. For details, refer to `arara` manual. Now for your case, put these somewhere in your document (I prefer just before `\documentclass`)

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% !arara: makeindex
% arara: bibtex: { files: [ journal, conference ] }
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
```

`!` makes an `arara` directive passive (i.e., a comment)

Code:

```
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% !arara: makeindex
% arara: bibtex: { files: [ journal, conference ] }
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
% arara: pdflatex: {synctex: yes}
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{multibib}

\newcites{journal, conference}{Refereed Journal Articles, Refereed Conference Publications}

\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{conference.bib}
  @inproceedings{entry1,
    author = {Author name},
    address = {address},
    booktitle = {Some conference},
    title = {Title},
    year = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{filecontents*}{journal.bib}
  @article{entry2,
    author = {Author name},
    journal = {Some Journal},
    title = {Title},
    year = {2013},
}
\end{filecontents*}
\begin{document}
Hi, this is an example of the multibib.
\bibliographystylejournal{plain}
\nocitejournal{*}
\bibliographyjournal{journal}

\bibliographystyleconference{plain}
\nociteconference{*}
\bibliographyconference{conference}

\end{document}
```

Save the above code and in TeXstudio, choose `arara` and compile. In my case, the short cut is `Alt`+`shift`+`F1` to invoke `arara`.

[image]

Comment: Such a nice answer 10/10!

Answer (score 0):

Replace the `bibtex %` command (`Options - Commands - bibtex`) with a custom script such as `bibtexall.cmd %`

The content of `bibtexall.cmd` is as follows. I learned from [the TeXstudio support forum](https://sourceforge.net/p/texstudio/discussion/907840/thread/abc9ef25/#bc3b), but I modified the script from there a little bit so it makes more sense to me.

```
@echo off
if "%1"=="" goto end

for %%f in ("%~dp1*.aux") do bibtex "%%f"

@echo on
:end
```

Place it right next to `bibtex.exe` (I'm using MiKTeX, so it's in `miktex/bin`)

Every time you update the custom bibliography, run bibtex in TeXstudio (F8).

It will parse every existing aux file in the same folder as the tex file, which could generate a lot of warnings saying some don't contain useful bibtex information, but I figure that's okay.

The Linux (bash) version can be found in the [`multibib`](https://ctan.org/pkg/multibib?lang=en) package manual.