# Problems with multibib and natbib with \defcitealias

Tags: natbib, arara, multibib

I have a problem getting two seperate bibliographies from a main `.bib` file. The other problem is the issue with the `\defcitealias` described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66778/citation-alias-with-multibib-and-natbib). I tried to reproduce the example in the link, but it is not working for me.

**MWE**

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: bibtex: { files: [ sec ] }
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex

\documentclass[a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}

\makeatletter
    \def\@mb@citenamelist{cite,citep,citet,citealp,citealt,citepalias,citetalias}
\makeatother

\usepackage{multibib}
\newcites{sec}{Other bibliographic references}

\defcitealias{manual-full}{International journal of logistics, issue 91}

\begin{document}
    
    \cite{article-full}
    
    \citesec{booklet-full}
    
    Something something something and then \citepaliassec{manual-full}.
    
    \bibliographystyle{plainnat}
    \bibliography{xampl}
    
    \let\noopsort\undefined
    \let\printfirst\undefined
    \let\singleletter\undefined
    \let\switchargs\undefined
    
    \bibliographystylesec{plainnat}
    \bibliographysec{xampl}
    
\end{document}
```

**Output**

[image]

Also, I am wondering what is ment with "To process your document, three runs of LATEX and two runs of BibTEX are required." in the [multibib manual](http://tug.ctan.org/tex-archive/macros/latex/contrib/multibib/multibib.pdf) p.4?
I compiled my `.tex` document in TeXStudio with F5 and F8, was this the way to do it?

**Edit**

I added the lines

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: bibtex: { files: [ sec ] }
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
```

for the compiling issue, but the problem/output stays the same.

**Edit2**

I followed the instructions recommended [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/183858/how-to-configure-texstudio-editor-for-multibib) and installed `arara`.

[image]

Then, I implemented `arara` in `TeXstudio`

[image]
[image]

Then, I tried to compile the data using `arara` but I got the error message:

```
Prozess gestartet: "C:/Users/.../AppData/Local/Programs/MiKTeX/miktex/bin/x64/arara.exe" -v -l "natbib+multibib"
Entschuldigung, aber arara.exe ist aus dem folgenden Grund fehlgeschlagen: MiKTeX could not find the script engine 'java.exe' which is required to execute 'arara'. Abhilfe: Make sure 'java.exe' is installed on your system. Die Log-Datei enthÃ¤lt hoffentlich alle Informationen, um MiKTeX wieder in Gang zu bringen. C:\Users\...\AppData\Local\MiKTeX\miktex\log\arara.log FÃ¼r weitere Information, besuchen Sie: https://miktex.org/kb/fix-script-engine-not-found
```

I think the `Java` issue is stated wrong, since I can run `arara` and it is already installed.

[image]

Does anyone know the cause of the error?

Comment: I think arara might be making this more complicated than it needs to be? I simply compiled the mwe you provide in TeXstudio (twice) and both bibliographies were produced. Not sure what the default is, but Options > Configure TeXstudio > Commands > BibTeX = `parallel bibtex -- ?*.aux` which evidently runs bibtex on all aux files.  I also successfully compiled in the terminal using `pdflatex mwe && bibtex mwe && bibtex sec && pdflatex mwe && pdflatex mwe`.

Comment: @jessexknight I changed `bibtex8.exe %` (default) to your suggestion `parallel bibtex -- ?*.aux` and now all references were not linkes i.e. labeled with `?`. Is there sommething else I have to change in TeXstudio?

Comment: Sorry, I think it's a linux/mac (me) vs windows (you?) thing: I think you should change it to `parallel bibtex8.exe -- ?*.aux`.

Comment: @jessexknight I am sorry, I ment `bibtex.exe %`. I am using windows, you are right. Then the change would be `parallel bibtex.exe -- ?*.aux` ? The error message I recieved with `parallel bibtex -- ?*` was that they `could not run the command parallel bibtex -- sec.aux`

Comment: Try removing `parallel`, so just `bibtex.exe -- ?*.aux` The `?*.aux` should be platform independent.

Comment: Without `parallel` I get two bibliographies. I have to move the four `\let...` commands between the two `bibliography` commands and now it works perfect. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @jessexknight Is there some source or documentation where I can find these kind of command lines?

Comment: Kind of. At the bottom of Options > Configure TeXstudio > Commands, there is a short blurb explaining the special characters. I myself wasn't sure where parallel came from but [apparently](https://linux.die.net/man/1/parallel) it's a linux thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using TeXstudio, you don't need to use Arara, since the following setting will run all the appropriate tools (latex, bibtex) in the right order:

**Options > Configure TeXstudio... > Commands > BibTeX = `bibtex -- ?*.aux`**
(or `bibtex.exe` on Windows).

The explanation at the bottom of the **Commands** page gives the explanation of `?*.aux`: *all .aux files in the current directory*.
By default, TeXstudio will run (pdf)latex and bibliography tool a reasonable number of times while compiling. These settings are defined in the **Build** page, but the default values all work fine for me. You may still have to compile twice.

You may also be interested to know about [magic comments](https://www.texdev.net/2011/03/24/texworks-magic-comments/) in TeXstudio.